# iOS drawing an Image within tableView using drawrect

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, tableview, drawrect

I have a UITableView which has a customtableView Cell. This has been subclassed. The tableViewCell has an image, label and a UIView (see attached screenshot)[image]

To make the line I put a UIView within the cell. I made the line in a separate class makeLine.swift using drawRect and designated this as the class for the view.

**Issue 1:** I want to change the color of the line depending on the TableRownumber. I have made an outlet for the UIView in the customCell class. I am guessing something needs to be done in cellForRowIndexPath method - but not sure what and how. I don't want to use an existing image for the line

Below is the code for making the line:

```
class LoginLine1: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let components: [CGFloat] = [107.0/255.0, 107.0/255.0, 107.0/255.0, 1.0]
        let color = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 70, 0)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

**Issue 2** once this line is made, I want to make it tapable and segue to next viewController. I have added tapGestureRecognizer to the UIView (which has the line). I have also enable User Interaction. The tap function is the following - but somehow its not working

```
@IBAction func lineTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

You could store the corresponding row number in a property of the custom cell, something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as CustomCell
    cell.rowNumber = indexPath.row

    ...

    return cell
}
```

In the custom cell, you create a custom setter for the property, something like this:

```
var rowNumber : Int {
    didSet {
        drawLineWithRowNumber(rowNumber)
    }
}
```

`drawLineWithRowNumber(rowNumber)` is the method which calls the `drawRect` method of your line class. In this way, you can pass the row number to the view which is responsible for drawing the line. You still have to implement any logic for picking a line color based on the given row number.

**Issue 2**

Instead of making the line tappable, you can better use `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to navigate to the next view controller, unless you need specific behaviour when the line will be tapped.